# White spaces in html

Tags: html, css

I have this sample output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfVuD.jpg). I cant cut the white spaces at the middle and retain what only is at the middle. Is there any way to do that?

here is my html code:

```
    <center>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="input-group col-xs-4">
                    <label for="usr">Bus Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="busName" required="required">
                </div>  

                <div class="input-group col-xs-4">
                     <label for="usr">Plate Number:</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="plateNo" required="required" maxlength="6">
                </div>

                <div class="input-group col-xs-4">
                      <label for="usr">Driver Assigned:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="driverAssigned" required="required">
                </div>

                <div><p></div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</center>
```

and here is my css code:

```
body {
  background: url("images/busView.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%
}

div.container {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, your question isn't clear. Do you mean actual whitespace characters? Are you referring to trimming whitespace from user input, or a layout issue?

Comment: Which whitespaces? (line and char numbers would be perfect)

Comment: I mean the layout. Sorry for that.

Comment: So you want the white box to wrap closely around it's content?

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 2):

By adding `width: auto;` most probably solve your issue. You may need to add some padding to make space around the form.

```
div.container {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mr0k0wm7/

Comment: This sounds like it should work - there is clearly some other CSS at work, as absolute positioned elements automatically have an unset width.

Comment: thanks it worked @DebRaj

Comment: @MatthewLymer You are right. Looks like he has some css with `width: 100%; ` applied to the `div.container`

Comment: @Dex Glad it worked for you!